# cluster 7000 csv files for machine learning

Tags: unsupervised-learning

I have around 7000 CSV files all containing similar coordinate data. I need to classify this data using unsupervised learning to prepare it to train a supervised algorithm. can I do this by clustering on a file-by-file basis or do I need to reduce the data into one sheet by summarizing each file somehow?

| Position [mm] | Density[kg/m³] |
| --- | --- |
| -0.924789 | 164.548694 |
| -0.914737 | 164.752771 |
| -0.904685 | 164.969708 |
| -0.894633 | 165.199505 |
| -0.884581 | 165.421192 |
| -0.874529 | 165.63477 |
| -0.864477 | 165.840239 |
| -0.854425 | 166.054321 |
| -0.844373 | 166.277018 |
| -0.834321 | 166.508329 |
| -0.824269 | 166.748254 |
| -0.814217 | 166.996794 |
| -0.804165 | 167.253948 |
| -0.794113 | 167.519716 |
| -0.784061 | 167.794099 |
| -0.774009 | 168.077095 |
| -0.763956 | 168.425204 |
| -0.753904 | 168.838424 |
| -0.743852 | 169.316756 |
| -0.7338 | 169.864012 |
| -0.723748 | 170.480193 |
| -0.713696 | 171.165298 |
| -0.703644 | 171.919328 |
| -0.693592 | 172.742282 |
| -0.68354 | 173.63416 |
| -0.673488 | 174.594963 |
| -0.663436 | 175.62469 |
| -0.653384 | 176.723342 |
| -0.643332 | 177.870035 |
| -0.63328 | 179.057714 |
| -0.623228 | 180.28638 |
| -0.613176 | 181.560452 |

etc.

Comment: Hmm... what you show is **not** a csv file...

Comment: what do you mean by "summarizing the file"? I would want to append them into one big table in whatever programming environment you use, that should be possible without creating a new gigantic file but that's impossible to say without knowing what kind of libraries and languages you use.

Comment: 1. will creating one big file differentiate each file for a clustering algorithm. or will a k-means file just group similar points together instead of looking at the whole picture.

Comment: 2. I have been trying to summarize each file using descriptive statistics which would allow me to create one big file where each row represents the descriptive statistics of each file. (Obviously, there are other kinds of calculations that can be run that would give single values to each file.)

Comment: I just want to know which is more effective at grouping files together for supervised learning.

Comment: @SergeBallesta this is not a csv file but an example of the data within the csv files